# Finding 1 occurrence of a value within array of variables in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am transitioning from SAS to R and have some difficulties "feeling" the language.

have the following dataset:

```
Key var1    var2    var3    var4    res1    res2    res3    res4
1   1   2   3   4   100 121 34565   4345
2   2   1   4   3   200 56  345 345
3   4   3   2   1   100 34  3   6
4   1   4   1   2   100 3   2   43
5   1   4   4   2   400 6   34  3

structure(list(Key = 1:5, var1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L), var2 = c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 4L), var3 = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L), var4 = c(4L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), res1 = c(100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 400L), res2 = c(121L, 
56L, 34L, 3L, 6L), res3 = c(34565L, 345L, 3L, 2L, 34L), res4 = c(4345L, 
345L, 6L, 43L, 3L)), .Names = c("Key", "var1", "var2", "var3", 
"var4", "res1", "res2", "res3", "res4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

where the `var1`-`var4` are for example number of credits in diff points of `time(var1 - Jun, var2-Jul,` etc)
The same goes for the array res1-res4 but it is an amount.
What I am trying to do is:

1. to find the first occurrence per Key ( working within the row) of 4 credits.So there should be a new variable for example FirstTime4Credits<- the index of the array(var1-var4).
   On the first row the result should be 4(var4=4 at the first row), the second 3, third row = 1, etc.
2. then I need to see at which point after reaching 4 the client goes back to 1 credit (first row -NA, second row=4, 3rd row 3, 4rd row = NA) and create a new variable representing this.
3. Finally I need to take the amounts from res1-res4 based on the moments the client reached 4 credits and 1 credit afterwards- 2 separate new variables.

The first task I managed to do:

```
varArray<-c("var1","var2","var3","var4")
d$first4<- apply(d[varArray],1,match,x=4)
```

where "d" is the data frame mentioned above imported.

the 2nd task is a show-stopper for me now. I am not sure how to start looking into elements within the list based on a value of variable.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd task (assuming it is among the `var` columns), you mentioned first row as NA, 2nd rows as `4`. In the example, the actual data for `var4` is 3.  3rd row 3 (data value 2), 4th row as NA.  In the 4th row, there is `1` that follows `4`.  It seems confusing.

Comment: Please avoid to ask many things in the same question. You don't even show what you have tried. This looks like do it for me. R is very different from SAS. It is a real programming language that have  a certain learning curve and that need more investment in your side.

Comment: You are right - I think I assumed I can easily hold the grasp of the language for some operations but it seems it will take more time. Apologize for not structuring the question very good!

Answer (score 1):

- 1st task

  ```
   varNames <- grep("var", colnames(d))
   indx <- max.col(d[, varNames], "first")
   indx
   #[1] 4 3 1 2 2
  ```
- 2nd task

  ```
  indx1 <- max.col(df[, varNames]==1, "last")
  indx2 <- ifelse(indx1>indx, indx1, NA)
  indx2
  #[1] NA NA  4  3 NA
  ```
- 3rd task

  ```
   resNames <- grep("res", colnames(d))
   d1 <- d[, resNames]
   d1[cbind(seq_along(indx), indx)]
   #[1] 4345  345  100    3    6

   d1[cbind(seq_along(indx2), indx2)] 
   #[1] NA NA  6  2 NA
  ```

#### data

```
 d <- structure(list(Key = 1:5, var1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L), var2 = c(2L, 
 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L), var3 = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L), var4 = c(4L, 3L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L), res1 = c(100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 400L), res2 = c(121L, 
 56L, 34L, 3L, 6L), res3 = c(34565L, 345L, 3L, 2L, 34L), res4 = c(4345L, 
 345L, 6L, 43L, 3L), first4 = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Key", 
 "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "res1", "res2", "res3", "res4", 
 "first4"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find the indices of occurences of 1 after a 4 occured:

```
df1 <- df[varArray] == 1 * (t(apply(df[varArray] == 4, 1, cumsum)) > 0)
bar <- function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, NA, x)
sapply((apply(df1, 1, which)), bar) 
#[1] NA NA  4  3 NA
```

I am not sure what you mean by 'amounts from res1-res4 based on the moments the client reached 4 credits and 1 credit afterwards'. Is this number somehow weighted by the difference between the indices from task 1) and 2)?

Comment: I am assuming he skipped one row when counting

Comment: Probably, that was confusing me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replay. The data is structured in such a way that var1 and res1 correspond to the same month. The same goes with var2 and res2, etc.. Meaning that if I find that 4 credits is hold in var3 I can extract the corresponding amount from res3. Thanks again for your prompt replays!